# ASP.net checkbox issue with IE 11

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, repeater, internet-explorer-11

i have a web page with check boxes in repeater in update panel, in IE11 and when i start checking boxes, a initial one goes fast, a second one slower, a third even slower, etc until checking box 10 takes about 18 seconds before a check mark appears and i can continue. its working fine in IE-8,IE-9. My page is loading in Quirks mode and there is no doctype specified on page. This happens when i specifically click on "Box" Area of check box, clicking on text area its working fine.

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="panel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" RenderMode="Inline">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="height: 100%;">
           <tr id="tr1" runat="server">
               <td>
                 <asp:Repeater ID="rptCheck" runat="server" DataSourceID="odsCheck" EnableViewState="true">
                   <HeaderTemplate>
                       <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="tblCheck" style="height: 100%;">
                   </HeaderTemplate>
                   <ItemTemplate>
                     <tr>
                       <td style=" height: 26px;">
                         <asp:CheckBox ID="chkUnselectedIngre" EnableViewState="false" ToolTip='<%# Eval("Name") %>' runat="server" Eval("Name")%>' style="cursor:pointer" AutoPostBack="false"/>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
             </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
  </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Edit : I have another check box list on same page and it is working fine in all browsers. when i copy all items from one check box list to another even with same number of checkboxes second one is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes from the postback triggered by your click on you checkbox. Solutions:

1. disable postback
2. use pure html: 
   `<input type="checkbox">`

Comment: i have disable to post back of check box but still issue is there.

Comment: if is it related to postback trigger then why this apper only in ie11?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your server is up-to-date, you may not have downloaded the update with the IE11 browser definitions.

Alternatively add a compatibility meta tag in the head of your page

Example:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
    ...
```